# django channels error: websocket connection failed

Tags: django, websocket, chat, django-channels

I have a django project what needs websocket connection to send message via django channels.
i coded my project and it's good in my system localhost but when i deploy the project in cPanel it returns WebSocket connection to `'wss://servername.com/' failed:` in a browser console.

**settings.py**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'rahapeyk.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    }
}
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rahapeyk.settings')

# application = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from social import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        'http': get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    }
)
```

**routings.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from social.consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**server.js**

```
const chat = new WebSocket(
    'wss://' + window.location.host + '/'
);

chat.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log('successfully');
}

chat.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log('unexpectedly happened');
}
```

how to keep the websocket connection when i deploy project without any error?

Comment: Try changing `'ws://' + window.location.host + '/'` in **server.js** to `'wss://' + window.location.host + '/'`.  In production you need to use `wss` as it is the secure version of `ws`.